# How to update select table using JPA custom single query

Tags: mysql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

> I want update work_withdraw table , set pending column of deposit
> table value quantity column of work_withdraw table.First of  all I
> want to pick deposit table id that id contain all the details, I find
> pending value from that id and that value set in work_withdraw table's
> quantity column. I write Below type of Custom Query and code by in my
> service class code it shows me type mismatch error, Required Long
> found Unit,If I change the Return type of query to Long It throw
> another "Update cannot return any thing"
> WorkWithdrawRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.repository

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Deposit
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.WorkWithdraw
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam

interface DepositRepository:JpaRepository<Deposit,Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("update WorkWithdraw  Ww  SET  Ww.quantity=(SELECT d.pending FROM Deposit  d WHERE d.id=Ww.id)")
    fun getPendingStatus(@RequestParam("id")id:Long)

}
```

> WorkWithdrawService.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.service

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.WorkWithdraw
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqUpdateWork
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqWorkWithdraw
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.DepositRepository
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.WorkerWithdrawRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class WorkWithdrawService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var workerWithdrawRepository: WorkerWithdrawRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var workerRepository: WorkerWithdrawRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositRepository: DepositRepository

  
    /**Update the work service*/
    fun updateWorkWithdraw(reqUpdateWork: ReqUpdateWork): WorkWithdraw {
        val updateWork = WorkWithdraw (
        id = reqUpdateWork.id,
        quantity = depositRepository.getPendingStatus(reqUpdateWork.id)
        )
        return workerWithdrawRepository.save(updateWork)
    }
}
```

> AdminWorkController.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.controller

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.AdvanceCash
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.Deposit
import com.nilmani.workload.entity.WorkWithdraw
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqUpdateWork
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqWorkWithdraw
import com.nilmani.workload.service.AdminService
import com.nilmani.workload.service.DepositService
import com.nilmani.workload.service.WorkWithdrawService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
class AdminWorkController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var workWithdrawService: WorkWithdrawService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositService: DepositService
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var adminService: AdminService


    /**Update the workWithdraw table when receive amterial*/
    @PutMapping("/updateWithdraw-work")
    fun updateWorkWithdraw(@ModelAttribute reqUpdateWork: ReqUpdateWork):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val deza= workWithdrawService.updateWorkWithdraw(reqUpdateWork)
        val respDeza = ReqUpdateWork(
            deza.id,
            deza.quantity
        )
        return ResponseEntity(respDeza,HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

> RequestUpdatWork.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.model.request

data class ReqUpdateWork(
    var id:Long=-1,
    var quantity:Long=-1,
)
```

> Deposit.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.entity

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Deposit(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val totalPiece:Long=-1,
    val totalDeposit:Long=-1,
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = WorkWithdraw::class,cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val workWithdraw: WorkWithdraw,
    var pending: Long =-1,
    val depositTime:LocalDateTime= LocalDateTime.now()
)
```

> WorkWithdraw.kt

package com.nilmani.workload.entity

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class WorkWithdraw(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val materialName:String="",
    val quantity: Long =-1,
    val withTime:LocalDateTime= LocalDateTime.now(),
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Worker::class,cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val worker: Worker?=null
)
```

> I get error in my service class at this  below point point

```
quantity = depositRepository.getPendingStatus(reqUpdateWork.id)
```

> And the error is below

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Long
Found:
Unit
```

> I do not understand how to handle this type of situation,I tried to
> solve this issue last 3 day's but not able to solve according
> requirement
> Do not know which type of parameter value passed inside @RequestParam
> in my repository class

Comment: Can you also include the entity code for `Deposit` ?

Comment: Now you can check I added Deposit  details services

Comment: I didn't ask for the deposit services class, I asked for the `Deposit` entity class.

Comment: Now you can see my Deposit Entity class